# conditionally inject device-specific Angular code at build time

Tags: angularjs, gulp, webpack

I've joined a project that uses Angular+Gulp+Webpack+Bower.

The project is built for different devices like so:

`gulp deviceA`

`gulp deviceB`

For each different device type, I will have a module called device.js that provides different versions of the same functions eg

```
device.foo();
device.bar();
```

I would like to conditionally inject the correct version of device.js at build time depending on the parameter passed to Gulp.  device.js should be available application-wide and before the application starts.

If I tackle it in a non-Angular way, I could easily inject some self-executing code into index.html at build time that provides the device object globally.  However, I want to make it more Angular-friendly so that I can eg use $rootScope to broadcast device events to the app.

My understanding is that an Angular Provider would suit my needs.  Is that correct, and if so, what would be the correct way to inject the appropriate Provider at build time?

Comment: Can't you use gulp to specify which device.js to delploy to the path that your angular app is looking for to resolve a dependency?

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say it's been a long day and I've no idea why that didn't automatically spring to mind!  Assuming I do it that way, would you say a Provider is still the best way to go?

Comment: You mean making device.js an angular provider like a factory or service?

Comment: I've coded one of them already as a factory but wondering if a Provider makes more sense because of the following line from the Angular description of Providers 

"You should use the Provider recipe only when you want to expose an API for application-wide configuration that must be made before the application starts. This is usually interesting only for reusable services whose behavior might need to vary slightly between applications."

I'm asking in case there's some limitation of factories that I've failed to consider.

Comment: If you're doing most of the configuration at the build level, then you might get away with just using a factory.  Maybe you can start with that and if it has limitations, look into using a full-blown provider.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks.